# Poor WiFi reception in a Lenovo T400s

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I have a BGN PCI express WiFi card on my Lenovo T400S.
I am running Windows 7.

The reception with the card is simply horrible. I sit on top of my access point and I still cannot get the full signal strength.

I removed Lenovo's connection manager and that improved the card's functionality.

Are there other ways to boost the card's performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth investigating any other Wi-Fi access points that are nearby, using a tool such as [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider). inSSIDer will tell you which channel each access point uses - so changing to a [less-crowded channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Channel_pollution) may help.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using it at home where there are only 2 computers using the mentioned AP. Even when only one is using it the performance is poor.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since at the end I found out that the antenna on the AP was not screwed properly...
I was sure I checked this...

Answer (score 0):

There is a Intel WiFi Link 5300 controller in the Lenovo T400s, which is pretty good (i used one of these to replace a Ralink WLAN controller, what an improvement! :).

If the Notebook is still under warranty, have the aerial connectors checked, if not, you might actually to this yourself:

> In models with wireless LAN card that
>   has three antenna connectors, plug the
>   gray cable (MAIN) into the jack
>   labeled TR1, the white cable (3rd)
>   into jack labeled RO or TR3, and the
>   black cable (AUX) into jack labeled
>   TR2 on the card.

Source: [ThinkPad T400s Hardware Maintenance Manual](http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CBYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.lenovo.com%2Fibmdl%2Fpub%2Fpc%2Fpccbbs%2Fmobiles_pdf%2F45m2271.pdf&ei=fZyBS5KHAaD20gTWgrivBA&usg=AFQjCNEVdLQAV-a1WnpT9LGv8qVnrgZDcA) (PDF)

Comment: OK. You caught me! part of the intention of the question was to see whether others were suffering from the same. I still have my warranty so I will go have it looked at.

Comment: @Shaihi - It might be just as simple as that, or a faulty controller, but in general the Intel 5300 is an excellent choice.

Comment: @Molly - Good to know. I will update this question once I attend to this. Thanks.